# Reddit oAuth 2 for Android "userless" app with Retrofit

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, retrofit, reddit

I'm trying to implement the Reddit oAuth2 (every app that utilizes Reddit content has to have this [implemented](http://is.gd/RrpcSx)) in Android based 'userless' application and I'm following the guidelines.

1. I [registered an app](http://is.gd/jNuval) and get the respective `client_id`.
2. I'm following this for [API guidelines](http://is.gd/lGNciC) and [this for Retrofit](http://is.gd/EOEz79) in order to properly write the Android code.

Hence, I've coded two approaches to the issue and it seems that neither works. The call in the appropriate Fragment is the same for the two options and it goes as follows:

```
    public void oAuth(){

    String bodyString = "grant_type=" + "https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client"
                       + "&device_id=" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    TypedInput requestBody = new TypedByteArray("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bodyString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    RedditAPI.sRedditAuth().redditAuth(requestBody, new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(TokenResponse tokenResponse, Response response) {
            Log.d("OATH_TAG", "oAuth() | YAY! :)");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("OATH_TAG", "oAuth() | NOOOOOoooooo.... :(");
        }
      });
    }
```

**OPTION 1:**

- the Retrofit interface:

  ```
    public interface RedditAuthInterface {
    @POST(Urlz.REDDIT_OATH2_PATH)
    void redditAuth(@Body TypedInput body, Callback<TokenResponse> result);

   }

     //the adapter
     public static RedditAuthInterface sRedditAuth() {
     if (sRedditAuthInterface == null) {
     RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter
                                    .Builder()
                                    .setClient(getAuthClient())
                                    .setEndpoint(Urlz.BASE_REDDIT_URL)
                                    .build();
      sRedditAuthInterface = restAdapter.create(RedditAuthInterface.class);
    }

    return sRedditAuthInterface;
   }


  /* support methods */
  private static OkClient getAuthClient() {

  final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
  okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(Static.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(Static.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  /*okHttpClient.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
      @Override
      public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
          String credential = Credentials.basic(BldCnfg.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID, BldCnfg.REDDIT_PASS);
          return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
      }

      @Override
      public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
          return null;
      }
   });*/

   okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(OAUTH_INTERCEPTOR);

    return new OkClient(okHttpClient);
  }

  private static final Interceptor OAUTH_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
      String credentials = BldCnfg.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID + ":" + BldCnfg.REDDIT_PASS; // REDDIT_PASS = "" as by API guides
      String string = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

      originalResponse.header("Authorization", string);
      originalResponse.header("Accept", "application/json");
      return originalResponse;
       }
   };
  ```
- result:

> RetrofitError: 401 Unauthorized

**OPTION 2:**

- the Retrofit interface:

  ```
     public interface RedditAuthInterface {
    @POST(Urlz.REDDIT_OATH2_PATH)
    void redditAuth(@Body TypedInput body, Callback<TokenResponse> result);

     }


       //the adapter
        public static RedditAuthInterface sRedditAuth() {
        if (sRedditAuthInterface == null) {
      RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter
                                    .Builder()
                                    .setClient(getConfuguredClient())
                                      .setRequestInterceptor(getRequestInerceptorPass())
                                    .setEndpoint(Urlz.BASE_REDDIT_URL)
                                    .build();
      sRedditAuthInterface = restAdapter.create(RedditAuthInterface.class);
  }

  return sRedditAuthInterface;
  }


  /* support methods */

  public static RequestInterceptor getRequestInerceptorPass() {
  RequestInterceptor rqInter = new RequestInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

          String credentials = BldCnfg.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID + ":" + BldCnfg.REDDIT_PASS; // REDDIT_PASS = "" as by API guides
          String string = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
          request.addHeader("Authorization", string);
          request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
      };

  return rqInter;
  }


  private static OkClient getConfuguredClient() {

  final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
  okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(Static.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(Static.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  return new OkClient(okHttpClient);
  }
  ```
- result:

It seems that I'm getting empty response (I only get "*" for scope). The successful response looks like this:

[image]

and header like this:

[image]

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Has anybody done this?

[The official Reddit github wiki](http://is.gd/30Mxg1) lacks Android examples (has in almost every other language, though).

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem before and make this [library](https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library) to handel OAuth2 in Android. and the library is an extension for Retrofit that simplifies the process of authenticating against an OAuth 2 provider.

Comment: Did you use this library to authenticate reddit users? Reddit's oauth implementation is a bit unusual so I'm not sure if the library will support it.

Comment: Actually, I didn't use it on Reddit. Read ReadMe in Repo, If it didn't serve your purpose tell me or you can fork the project and what you need

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image with the "empty" response, showing that you got `*` back as a scope, I suspect that your definition for the access token response is using camel case instead of snake case, so the JSON is not getting loaded properly into the Java object.